# C++ Delegate to member function using std::function and std::bind not calling function

Tags: c++, c++11, delegates, pointer-to-member

This is baffling me.  Below we have three classes, the Paddle class and two wrapper classes that call members of the Paddle object.

The Paddle object isn't working with the delegates, but works when invoked from wrapper classes.  All functions have the same signatures and overloads.

The compiler throws no errors, and the code runs fine but has the above unexpected behavior.

Why is this happening?

```
// sf::Transformable has 2 overloaded member functions:
//   void setPosition(float x, float y);
//   void setPosition(const Vector2f& position);

class Paddle : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {}

Paddle paddle{};

// wrap the calls in another class with the same overload signatures as paddle
// used to show delegate working with overloads
class A 
{
public:
    void setPosition(sf::Vector2f& v) {
        paddle.setPosition(v);
    }
    void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        paddle.setPosition(x, y);
    }
};

// inherit members from A
// used to show delegate working with inherited overloads
class B : public A {};

// delegate typedef
typedef std::function<void(float,float)> TranslateDelegate;

// create wrapper classes
A a{};
B b{};

// create 3 delegates
TranslateDelegate pda = std::bind(static_cast<void(A::*)(float, float)>(&A::setPosition), a, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
TranslateDelegate pdb = std::bind(static_cast<void(B::*)(float, float)>(&B::setPosition), b, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
TranslateDelegate pdp = std::bind(static_cast<void(Paddle::*)(float, float)>(&Paddle::setPosition), paddle, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

pda(300.f, 900.f); // sets paddle position correctly
pdb(300.f, 900.f); // sets paddle position correctly
pdp(300.f, 900.f); // DOES NOTHING!!
```

Comment: Shouldn't those instances be by-address ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It seems for paddle, I needed to pass the address to std::bind, unlike a and b:

```
TranslateDelegate pdp = std::bind(static_cast<void(Paddle::*)(float, float)>(&Paddle::setPosition), &paddle, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact that the function in A and B would work either in context or being called as static class functions.

Comment: It's because `bind` copies (or moves) its arguments. You should also be able to use `std::ref(paddle)` instead of `&paddle`.